# My first app in Xamarin looks like blank application

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I created Blank App (android) in ViusalStudio.
I added only a button.
When i deploy my app and test it, all i get is app-name bar (look of blank application).

What's wrong ? I was waiting very long and nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

In the main activity make sure you uncomment the line of code SetContentView so it uses the axml file for its layout

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i discovered it myself too ^^.
That was sooo stupid to overlook it.
But it was my first contact with xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without see how your code looks, but probably you don't set your Layout in OnCreate()

```
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.'your_layout');
```